# Reading .c000 partitioned parquet file using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

This is my first time using pyspark, and I want to transform some parquet files into csv, following is my code

```
spark= SparkSession.builder.master("local").enbaleHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

df=spark.read.parquet("path_to_my_folder")

df.write.csv("target_path")
```

but this code can only read folders with .parquet files, not for .c000

the error is Could not read footer for file...

I don't know if I'm using the correct function or set up, thanks

Comment: Can you check if the parquet file which you are trying to read is not corrupted

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure they are not corrupted

Comment: can you give an example of a full file name?

Comment: sorry I cannot provide a full name because I don't own the data source, but basiclly is part-00034-somehashcode.c000. From my understanding, I think this read.parquet function should be able to read either a folder or a single file, but I cann't read neither of them now

Comment: So I have never seen a parquet file not ending in `.snappy.parquet`. Anyhow, how do you run this code?

Comment: I just want to run the above code to transfer some data and do some calculations. The weird thing is, I tried to generate some parquet files using my own csv data, which all end in .c000.snappy.parquet. If I delete the snappy.parquet, I can still read them using the above code. But this code just cannot run for the data I want to use. I start to suspect my data but since I download them from HDFS I think they should be ok.

Comment: I've written pyspark dataframe into aws athena `df.write.mode("append").format("hive")` and when I navigate to its source S3 all parquet files are in `.c000` format as well. Did you find the solution?